# Plink. Error: No people remaining after --keep

Tags: plink

I'm trying to subset individuals from the ACB population from the file named allconcat39.vcf , using Plink 1.9. For that, I created a text file (tab delimited) in R called indACB, which looks like this:

```
head indACB.txt 
684_HG01879 684_HG01879
685_HG01880 685_HG01880
686_HG01882 686_HG01882
687_HG01883 687_HG01883
688_HG01885 688_HG01885
689_HG01886 689_HG01886
690_HG01889 690_HG01889
691_HG01890 691_HG01890
694_HG01894 694_HG01894
695_HG01896 695_HG01896
```

when I run the following code:

```
./plink --vcf allconcat39.vcf --keep indACB.txt --recode --out allconcat39ACB
```

the following error occurs:

```
Error: No people remaining after --keep.
```

I made sure than the vcf and the indACB.txt file had compatible individual IDs and sample IDs. I don't know where else the problem can be. Any thoughts? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved in another forum by Christopher Chang: Add --double-id to your command line; otherwise plink treats '_' as a delimiter between the FID and IID.